# Docker. uninitialized constant Watir::Browse

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, docker, docker-compose, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm trying to run `watir` chrome driver in headless mode on docker container. ruby on rails.

Here is my docker config:

```
# https://github.com/codelittinc/dockerfiles/blob/master/ruby/Dockerfile
FROM ruby:2.2

# Mount any shared volumes from host to container @ /share
ENV HOME /home/rails/webapp

# Install dependencies and rails-api
RUN apt-get update -qq && apt-get install -y build-essential libpq-dev nodejs xvfb chromium

WORKDIR $HOME

# Install gems
ADD Gemfile* $HOME/
RUN bundle install

ADD . $HOME

# Configure an entry point, so we don't need to specify
# "bundle exec" for each of our commands.
ENTRYPOINT ["bundle", "exec"]

CMD ["rails", "server", "--binding", "0.0.0.0"]
```

**Error:**
Getting error on browser initialization:

```
?[33mapp_1       |?[0m NameError (uninitialized constant Watir::Browse):
?[33mapp_1       |?[0m
?[33mapp_1       |?[0m app/services/watir_test_service.rb:15:in `test_me'
?[33mapp_1       |?[0m app/controllers/watir_test_controller.rb:4:in `index'
```

class:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'watir-webdriver'
require 'headless'

class Watir_test_service

  def test_me

    headless = Headless.new
    browser = Watir::Browse.new :chrome

    begin
      headless.start
      browser.goto "http://google.com"

      puts browser.title
    ensure
      browser.close
      headless.destroy
    end
  end
end
```

What can be a reason? `xvfb`, `chromium` are installed on container. There was no error on building the container.

Comment: From which file you trying to run `watir`? Share a full error message, please.

Comment: updated the question with full class file. running simply from the controller `test = Watir_test_service.new
      test.test_me`

Comment: I suppose you should use `require 'watir'` instead of `require 'watir-webdriver'`.

Comment: you should use capybara-webkit , a lot better than headless

Comment: Same, `cannot load such file -- watir` if i use `require 'watir'`

Comment: i did used `phantomjs` a lot in some JAVA project. So much bugs and small problems arise... If its possible to setup real browser, want to go for it.

Comment: Were you able to figure this out?

Comment: yeah but sry don't have that source code anymore :(